# How to save foreign key fields in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `Question` and `Answer` model as follows:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    text = model.textField()

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = model.ForeignKey(Question)
    text = model.textField()
    correct = model.BooleanField()
```

i want to save four answers while saving a question and in which only one answer can be correct. Also one answer must be correct out of four.

Comment: what is error in that models

Comment: its just a sample may contain spelling mistakes.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I think your best option is to make use of Django Forms and do that validation on its clean method.

An example of its use can be found in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/validation/ . It provides nice documentation and shows you how to validate fields on a form (which is what you need). If you don't know how to create a form, visit this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/ first and then check out how it is done and check if it is what you were looking for. If it isn't, try to make your question a bit clearer, please =)